ASP.NET Core 8 custom Web API endpoint
I am relatively new to ASP.NET Core 8, and am trying to add a custom endpoint to my Web API, but I am getting a 400 error. I've spent some time scouring Google trying to figure out what the problem is, but cannot find a clear answer. This is just a proof of concept for a larger project, so does not have to be perfect.
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
                  "id": [ "The value 'GetOfferByKey' is not valid."] 
              },
    "traceId": "0HN32SVRCJJQ4:00000002"
}

Here is part of my controller. Not sure what I am missing. The offending endpoint is at the bottom. Thanks for your help.
public class OffersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly VDM_LoaderContext _context;
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<VDM_LoaderContext> _contextFactory;
    private readonly OfferService _offerService;

    public OffersController(VDM_LoaderContext context, IDbContextFactory<VDM_LoaderContext> factory)
    {
        _contextFactory = factory;
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Offers
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Offer>>> GetOffers()
    {
        return await _context.Offers.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/Offers/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Offer>> GetOffer(int id)
    {
        var offer = await _context.Offers.FindAsync(id);

        if (offer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return offer;
    }

    /***** this is the endpoint causing problems *****/
    // GET: api/Offers/GetOfferByKey/{offerKey}
    [Route("api/Offers/GetOfferByKey/{offerKey}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Offer>> GetOfferByKey(int offerKey)
    {
        var offer = await _contextFactory.CreateDbContext()
                                         .Offers
                                         .Where(o => (o.OfferKey == null ? string.Empty : o.OfferKey).Equals(offerKey))
                                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync();            

        if (offer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return offer;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

I tried to add a [Route] attribute, but that did not help. I found a post saying to make sure your WebConfig.cs file has attribute routing enabled with line:
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

However, my project does not have a WebConfig.cs file. I am using .NET 8.

Can you share the Url you are using with the /{id} you are passing to the endpoint?

here is a URL example http://localhost:5170/api/Offers/GetOfferByKey/.DST.MUSD9127.

could you try setting the route like this: [HttpGet("GetOfferByKey/{offerKey}")] public async Task<ActionResult<Offer>> GetOfferByKey(int offerKey) {    //code } . make sure your data type in the url match with the parameter type which is offerKey.  set builder.Services.AddControllers(); in Program.cs file
